# How to handle the changes happened in realm db table for synchronization?

Tags: react-native, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-js

I am using `realm js` for my `react native` app and the app has to be addressed to work offline and online, hence I need to have synchronization between the server database`(Postgres/MySql/Oracle)` and `realm` database.

1. How should I log the changes(Update delete create) that happened in the database to achieve syncing?
2. Any inspiration on how we should handle the synchronization?
   Note: Cannot spend money on buying Realm Object Server and any open-source recommendation will be helpful.

Comment: You could add an `isSynced` field, when returning online you could query Realm for rows that have not been synced to your remote database. Once synced, set the field to true.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. @Dan
This I can consider as an option but I am more looking for any open-source adapter or anything which can handle it for me.